# How can I have a view retain its nested child state upon return as opposed to going to its parent using ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im created tabs using ui-router where some of tabs have children/grandchildren states. How can I have tab view remember its history, that is, go back into its previous used state upon return. I created a **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/garrettmac/pen/rxMJyV)** to demonstrate this.

> 1) users goes into a tab
>
> [image]
>
> 2) user goes into a nested view of that tab
>
> [image]
>
> 3) user goes into another tabs view
>
> [image]
>
> 4) if the user goes back into the first tab they go into the parent view of the tab. How can I have them go back into the child view of that tab (seen in #2)?
>
> [image]

**JS**

```
    .state('sidemenu.parent.child1', {
      url: "/child1",
      views: {
        'shared-child-view' :{
          templateUrl: "child1.html"
        }
      }
    })
       .state('sidemenu.parent.child2', {
      url: "/child2",
      views: {
   'shared-child-view': {
     templateUrl: "child2.html"
   }
    }
    })
  .state('sidemenu.parent.grandchild1', {
     url: "/grandchild1",
      views: {
   'shared-child-view': {
     templateUrl: "grandchild1.html"
   }
    }
    })
```

**html**

```
     <div class="tabs tabs-top button-bar">
     <a class="tab-item" 
         ng-class="{active:$state.includes('sidemenu.parent.child1') || $state.includes('sidemenu.parent.grandchild1')}"  
         ui-sref="sidemenu.parent.child1">
          <b> Child1</b>
     </a>


      <a class="tab-item" 
           ng-class="{active:$state.includes('sidemenu.parent.child2')}" 
           ui-sref="sidemenu.parent.child2">
          <b>Child2</b>
       </a>

  ...............

     <div ui-view name="shared-child-view"></div>
```

I have made a minor updates in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/garrettmac/pen/pgNyRB) where it now shows its current state.

Comment: Any particular reason you want the full example to be (only) off-site instead of (also) in a collapsed stack-snippet?

Comment: @Deduplicator no particular reason other than I haven't done  a collapsed stack-snippet before, but you're right I should probably start.

Comment: Are you opposed to using `$state.go` in an `ng-click` instead of (the cleaner) `ui-sref`? `$state.go` lets you dynamically set parameters so you could have some kind of state appended to your parent controller that "remembers" if a grandchild tab is open.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to fix your states. For example:

```
'sidemenu.parent.grandchild1'
```

should be:

```
'sidemenu.parent.child1.grandchild1'
```

And you'll have to change the link and add a ui-view in your template:

```
<script id="child1.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <div>
    <a class="button" ui-sref="sidemenu.parent.child1.grandchild1">
      <b>go to grandchild</b>
    </a>
    <div ui-view name="shared-child-view"></div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking but when I tried it it wouldn't allow me to transition to the grandchild state without going to the the child state first. I should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: hmm ... works for me. Are you sure you updated the template as well? Or maybe I don't understand the problem. I can navigate to '...child1.grandchild1', then navigate to '...child2', then hit the browser 'back' and I'm at '...child1.grandchild1'

Comment: That adds another ui-view inside the child1.html and im not looking to do that. And yes, I can use the back button in either of them and this results in what Id like, however, I  would like to attain this result by clicking the 'child1 tab' for the second time and not the 'back button', my issue is by clicking the  'child1 tab' the second time (after clicking another tab) it returns to its 'child1 tab''s state not the 'grandchild1's state which is what I'd like.